# Как заметить удерживание кнопки в Unity через скрипт не в этой кнопке?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Я читал, что надо делать что-то с Event Triggers, но там показано только как делать это, когда скрипт находиться в самой кнопке. Я делаю игру для телефонов, где персонаж двигается по нажатию по кнопкам на экране. Причем я хочу сделать это все в одном скрипте. Возможно ли это, или мне придеться создавать 4 разных скрипта для 4 разных кнопок? Я собираюсь сунуть этот скрипт в игрока. Надеюсь понятно написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имея ссылку на кнопку, можно подписаться на событие её нажатия. Такой вариант гораздо проще дебажить и контролировать, чем тригеры (и к тому же никаких публичных методов). Выглядеть это будет, примерно, так:

```
Button _leftButton;

Button _rightButton;

void Start()
{
    _leftButton.onClick.AddListener(MoveLeft); //onClick - событие нажатия кнопки
    _rightButton.onClick.AddListener(MoveRight); //AddListener - добавление метода в качестве "слушателя" события.
}

void MoveLeft()
{
    //Идёт налево - песнь заводить
}

void MoveRight()
{
    //направо - сказку говорит
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я когда-то давно это запостил и забыл. Теперь это кажется так легко.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем **Event Trigger** на кнопку.

add New Event Type -> PointerClick

Создаём в скрипке игрока метод

```
 publick void ClickButton1(){
// делаем что-то
}
```

Кидаем этот скрип в **Event Trigger** и выбираем этот метод.
Так же с остальными.